# Can't read all of the strings

Tags: c, string, scanf, fgets

```
int main()
{
int epilogi,n=1,x,i;
char temp[2];
list=malloc(n*sizeof(struct address));
printf("Lista taxidromikon dieuthinseon\n");
printf("1. Eisagogi stoixeion\n");
printf("2. Diagrafi stoixeion\n");
printf("3. Emfanisi listas\n");
printf("4. Eksodos\n\n");
printf("Epilekste dinontas dinontas ena arithmo apo to 1 eos to 4\n");
while (scanf("%d", &epilogi)!=4)
{
if (epilogi==1)
{
while (strcmp("n",temp))
{
printf("Dose onomateponimo, dieuthinsi, poli, xora kai taxidromiko kodika\n");
fgets(list[n-1].name,80,stdin);
fgets(list[n-1].addr,50,stdin);
fgets(list[n-1].city,50,stdin);
fgets(list[n-1].country,30,stdin);
scanf("%[^\n]%d", &list[n-1].code);
printf("------------------------------------\n");
printf("Thelete na eisagete allo stoixeio?(Pliktrologiste y gia nai n gia oxi)\n");
fgets(temp,2,stdin);
printf("\n");
if (strcmp("n",temp))
{
n=n+1;
list=realloc(list,n*sizeof(struct address));
}
}
```

[edit] ok so I fixed the 90% of the problem. Now the program succcessfully asks me to input all 6 but not the temp string.Thats because there is a newline in the buffer created by the last scanf.How can I make the fgets ignore it?

Comment: `fgets` should work.Show what you have done...

Comment: Please show some more lines of code

Comment: @ohyez96 what's `temp` doing for the first time?

Comment: In this program i choose option 1 to input the Information(name, address,city,country) of someone. The temp string is used to ask the user whether he wants to add another one or not

Comment: ok I fixed the main problem. It scans all of my strings properly except temp because of what you said. The point is I can put a %[^\n] and deal with the problem with scanf but how can I deal with the newline that scanf stores in the buffer?I will edit the post so everyone can see the new program

Comment: Tried it. Works like a charm!Thank you very much,topic closed

Answer (score 1):

Are you compiling with the `-Wall` option?
The line

```
scanf("%d", list[n-1].code);
```

if `list` is a pointer to `struct address` should produce a warning, because you are supposed to pass `code`'s address. Try

```
scanf("%d", &list[n-1].code);
```

, it works for me. Keep `fgets` for the strings, as suggested.

Comment: Tried it. Still doesnt work. It skips scanning the list[n-1].code and now it skips scanning and the temp string. [edit] no i am not compiling with -wall

Comment: Are you separating your inputs to `fgets` by newlines? It scans until and end of line is reached (or maximum size is read).

Comment: of course i press enter everytime I input something

Comment: @ohyez96 there is no "try" with this error. its a flat-out bug and it *has* to be fixed .

Comment: @WhozCraig so this means it has something to do with the compiler?

Comment: He/she means that you *absolutely* must use `scanf("%d", &list[n-1].code);` since `scanf()` expects `int *` as the second argument.

Comment: @ohyez96 *what* has something to do with the compiler? I'll say this differently. If you're code doesn't have the suggested change in this answer *now*, it is ill-formed. You said "Tried it". This isn't a "try-it" answer. This answer points out a flat-out *bug*. Think Yoda wearing Nikes. There is No Try: Just Do It.

Comment: the test on the compiler i added is with the & included in that scanf. I am sorry for not renewing the post.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix `scanf()` with `fgets()`.

Recommend dropping `scanf()` calls.
To read a number, call `fgets()` and `aoti()` or `strtol()`.
This could be done in another function.

```
  int ohyez96_GetInt(int *dest) {
    char buf[50];
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) return EOF;
    // various error checking omitted for now.
    *dest = atoti(buf);
    return 1;
  }

  // while (scanf("%d", &epilogi)!=4)
  while (ohyez96_GetInt(&epilogi) == 1)
  ...
  // scanf("%[^\n]%d", &list[n-1].code);
  if (ohyez96_GetInt(&list[n-1].code) != 1) return -1;
```